# Receiving Windows Live friend requests at invalid Windows Live ID

Tags: office-365

My email address is being bombarded with Windows Live friend requests. The "to" field on these emails is clearly my email address, which I try to use as my Windows Live ID to sign in and change my email preferences.

However, the Windows Live website claims that my email address is not a valid or active Windows Live ID. Further, it does not provide a way to look up my ID based on my email address.

Here is the password reset page. Notice that it only allows password lookup, which doesn't help if you don't know your ID:

http://account.live.com/password/reset

How do I find out what my Windows Live ID is so that I can stop these emails?

Comment: first of all you need to stop using hotmail.

Comment: I don't have a hotmail account, and if I do by some crazy chance, it sure as hell isn't associated with my gmail account. Are you going to go through the steps which I took the time to outline above, or are you going to sit back and judge people based on misconceptions?